# How to resize LVM in Redhat

Tags: linux, redhat, lvm, partition, diskmanagement

I have a VM with Redhat 6.8 that originally started with a 60GB disk 1. In VMware I increased the size to 100GB. I would like to increase the /tmp volume from 2GB to 5GB. I assume I need to resize the sda2 partition first and then increase the LV. I tried `echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/2\:0\:0\:0\/device/rescan` and then `resize2fs /dev/sda` but it said it was busy. Not sure what commands I need or what the the order is... Here's my system info -

```
$ fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0000555c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          26      204800   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              26        7833    62708736   8e  Linux LVM
```

---

```
$ lsblk
NAME                            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                              11:0    1  3.6G  0 rom
sda                               8:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─sda1                            8:1    0  200M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                            8:2    0 59.8G  0 part
  ├─system-swap (dm-0)          253:0    0   10G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─system-root (dm-1)          253:1    0   10G  0 lvm  /
  ├─system-opt (dm-2)           253:2    0   10G  0 lvm  /opt
  ├─system-tmp (dm-3)           253:3    0    2G  0 lvm  /tmp
  ├─system-var_log (dm-4)       253:4    0    1G  0 lvm  /var/log
  ├─system-var (dm-5)           253:5    0   10G  0 lvm  /var
  ├─system-home (dm-6)          253:6    0   10G  0 lvm  /home
  └─system-var_log_audit (dm-7) 253:7    0    1G  0 lvm  /var/log/audit
```

---

```
$ lvdisplay /dev/system/tmp
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/system/tmp
  LV Name                tmp
  VG Name                system
  LV UUID                QOy6T3-vVnK-fJ0o-hyfY-gPYf-IC61-YDLQn1
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time hardlogs.localdomain, 2014-02-19 12:09:47 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                2.00 GiB
  Current LE             512
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:3
```

Comment: Suggest checking out this link: http://blog.gulfsoft.com/2009/01/adding-disk-space-to-linux-vm-in-vmware.html. The rough order is: add disk space in VMWare; create a new partition /dev/sda3 using `fdisk`; use the `pvcreate` command to get the LVM to see it; add space to the `system` volume group with the `vgextend` command; assign that space to the `/dev/system/tmp` logical volume using the `lvextend` command. FINALLY! You can extend the filesystem using `resize2fs` on `/dev/system/tmp` (not `/dev/sda`). Good luck!

Comment: @JeremyDover He can resize the underlying partition/volume whitout creating new partitions/pvdevices. Please see my answer.

Comment: @shodanshok: Agree it should be possible, but I have never had success doing it on CentOS 6 VMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After partition resize, you should reboot the system to be 100% sure that kernel recognizes the new size. After that:

- you had to resize the LVM volume, issuing `lvextend /dev/system/tmp -L 5G`
- you had to resize the filesystem, issuing `resize2fs /dev/system/tmp`

Please pay **much** attention to issuing the above command against the correct devices. For example, your previous `resize2fs` was plain and dangerously wrong, as you **must not use sda** as target, rather the LVM volume.